# Python Pandas: If a column value equals a string, set the value of a different column cell to a certain string

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

BabyDataSet = [('Bob', 968), ('Jessica', 155), ('Bob', 77), ('John', 578), ('Mel', 973)]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=BabyDataSet, columns=['Names', 'Births'])
```

What I'd like to do is: If the name is "Bob", then set the value of its "Births" to "Unknown" using Pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way with `numpy(np.where)`...

```
>>> df['Births'] = np.where(df.Names == 'Bob', 'unkown', df.Births)
>>> df
     Names  Births
0      Bob  unkown
1  Jessica     155
2      Bob  unkown
3     John     578
4      Mel     973
```

In case you have multiple values to compare, you can create a list to compare like below and then apply with `isin`.

```
>>> n = ['Bob']   # you use for more values like ['Bob', 'rob', 'pike']
>>> df.loc[df.Names.isin(n), 'Births'] = "unkown"
>>> df
     Names  Births
0      Bob  unkown
1  Jessica     155
2      Bob  unkown
3     John     578
4      Mel     973
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `.loc` to assign the values to one or more columns based on the boolean condition; `df['Names'].eq('Bob')` in this case

```py
df.loc[df['Names'].eq('Bob'), 'Births'] = 'Unknown'

     Names   Births
0      Bob  Unknown
1  Jessica      155
2      Bob  Unknown
3     John      578
4      Mel      973
```